# Why do some signals not allow signal filtering using Fourier transformation?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have tried Fourier transformation on two types of data:

`Sample 1:`

```py
 [5.22689618e-03 2.41534315e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.44972858e-01
 4.25280086e-02 9.33815370e-01 3.03247287e-01 2.30718622e-01
 3.67055310e-03 1.08563452e-01 1.65198349e+00 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 3.81988895e-01 5.76292398e-02 4.30815942e-01
 1.26064346e+00 1.22264457e-01 9.20206465e-01 5.10205014e-02
 1.69624045e-02 1.27946761e-04 9.85479035e-02 1.47322503e-03
 5.88801835e-01 9.14815956e-04 1.58679916e-02 1.80580638e-04
 1.33877873e-02 4.31785412e-01 4.29998728e+00 7.28365507e-02
 2.93196111e-01 6.46923082e-01 1.64020382e+00 2.66995573e-01
 1.73472541e+00 1.20450527e+00 2.93713233e-01 4.37012291e-02]
```

`Sample 2:`

```py
 [1.63397428e-05 5.06326672e-05 5.07890481e-05 3.27493146e-05
 6.19592537e-04 2.14127001e-04 3.31584036e-04 3.67715480e-05
 8.80083850e-05 2.70784860e-05 1.82332876e-05 1.13016894e-04
 9.62697824e-06 6.82677776e-06 1.55218678e-05 1.17480350e-04
 6.16809229e-05 7.51721123e-05 1.71455229e-04 3.89279781e-05
 4.14875499e-04 2.91402507e-05 2.07895269e-04 3.54011492e-04
 1.81316474e-06 2.28406092e-06 1.75001077e-04 3.21301398e-04
 2.77558089e-05 4.87684894e-04 1.91564056e-05 5.09892912e-06
 1.91527601e-04 4.01062880e-05 8.71198341e-06 2.87598374e-04
 1.81759066e-04 4.45384356e-05 1.90984648e-05 5.30995670e-04
 9.18908105e-05 6.19051866e-04 7.01213246e-06 1.97357403e-05
 1.52822474e-06 4.44353810e-05 2.12599086e-04 1.10231829e-04
 3.34317235e-05 1.10217651e-04 2.27115357e-05 2.43621107e-04
 9.59827677e-05 1.99824695e-04 1.76506191e-04 2.83759047e-04
 3.95528472e-05 1.04707169e-04 1.92821332e-05 1.69779942e-04
 2.82886397e-04 1.42531512e-04 1.25545297e-05 6.64785458e-05
 2.49983906e-04 7.36739683e-05 1.75280514e-04 6.63189677e-05
 7.10295246e-06 1.45455223e-04 1.71038217e-04 1.80725103e-05
 6.81610965e-05 5.38084605e-04 7.54303898e-05 1.74061569e-05
 1.26723836e-04 8.94035463e-05 9.10723041e-05 1.54759188e-05
 4.62195919e-05 4.98443430e-04 1.13484031e-04 6.36021767e-05
 4.85053842e-05 6.72420582e-05 3.24306672e-04 1.92741144e-05
 7.68752096e-04 3.27063864e-04 2.19143305e-05 7.59406815e-05
 3.59140998e-05 5.66567689e-04 2.57783290e-04 1.20276603e-04
 1.99017206e-05 3.27490253e-04 9.39513533e-05 1.01252991e-04]
```

I tried implementing Fourier filter transformation to extract signals from the original set but both signal does not show same findings. The `sample 1` doesn't extract any function while `sample 2` allows it, as shown in the figure

A partial code for the analysis is presented below.

```py
# Positive sample
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = signal
t = np.arange(len(signal))
dt = 1

## Compute the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)
n = len(t)
fhat = np.fft.fft(f,n)                     # Compute the FFT
PSD = fhat * np.conj(fhat) / n             # Power spectrum (power per freq)
freq = (1/(dt*n)) * np.arange(n)           # Create x-axis of frequencies in Hz
L = np.arange(1,np.floor(n/2),dtype='int') # Only plot the first half of freqs
#print('PSD value is', PSD, '\n\nfhat is', fhat, '\n\nfrequency is', freq)
plt.plot(freq, PSD)

# Extracting datasets ## Use the PSD to filter out noise
indices = PSD > 0.2       # Find all freqs with large power
low_indices = PSD < 0.2  # Find all freqs with small power
PSDnoise = PSD[low_indices]  # store smaller freqs 
PSDclean = PSD * indices  # Zero out all others
fhat_noise = low_indices * fhat
fhat = indices * fhat     # Zero out small Fourier coeffs. in Y
ffilt = np.fft.ifft(fhat) # Inverse FFT for filtered time signal
noise = np.fft.ifft(fhat_noise)
```

I repeat this process on the noise data for multiple times and the graph I obtained from three steps is:

[image]

May I Know why these two functions behave differently?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please read [mre]. There are many lines of code whose output is not used. It is a lot easier to see what you are doing if you keep your code succinct and only with meaningful lines. Right now it takes too much effort to read your code.

Comment: @ChrisLuengo apologies for the inconvenience will update the question as per suggestions